# Symmetry group of a modified quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, symmetry, harmonic-oscillator, group-theory

Here is my Hamiltonian:
$$H = \frac{1}{2m} p_1^2 + \frac{1}{4m} p_2^2 + \frac{1}{6m} p_3^2 + \frac{1}{2} k^2 (q_1^2 + 2q_2^2 + 3q_3^2),$$ where $q_i$ and $p_i$are canonical variables, in the sense that $[q_a,p_b] = \delta_{a,b} i$.

How can I identify the Lie Group of the continuous symmetries of $H$ acting on $(q_a,p_b)$?

Comment: The WP section on SU(3) is not clear?

Comment: Very clear, but I have a few more questions: 1) How can I show that at each energy level the states form an irriducible representation of G? I think that is sufficient to say that the elements of SU(3) map a state into another state with the same energy, because the Hamiltonian is invariant under SU(3). Therefore is sufficient to calculate the number of states at each energy level and show that this number corresponds to the dimension of an irriducible representation of SU(3).

Comment: 2) If I perturbate the Hamiltonian: $H_\lambda = H + \lambda(q_1^2p_2^2 + 4q_2^2p_1^2 -2q_1p_2q_2p_1 -2q_2p_1q_1p_2)$, it is correct to say that the SU(2) subgroup of SU(3) is the group of symmetry of hamiltonian?

Comment: The degeneracy of the 3D isotropic oscillator is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317323/degeneracy-of-the-isotropic-harmonic-oscillator). The dimensionality of the irreducible reps of SU(3)  is, [of course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Representations_of_the_SU(3)_group)  (p+1)(q+1)(p+q+2)/2.

Answer (score 2):

Through the obvious *canonical* rescaling,
$$
q_1=Q_1, \qquad q_2=Q_2/\sqrt{2}, \qquad q_3=Q_3/\sqrt{3},\\
p_1=P_1, \qquad p_2=P_2 ~ \sqrt{2}, \qquad  p_3=P_3~\sqrt{3},
$$
which preserves the commutation relation, $[Q_a,P_b] = \delta_{a,b} ~i I$.

It transforms the hamiltonian into the ("unmodified") isotropic 3D SHO, whose symmetry is well-known to be [U(3)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/301178/why-3-dim-isotropic-harmonic-oscillators-symmetry-is-not-o6-but-u3). Since, however, an over-all phase change is immaterial/unphysical in QM, the focus of your attention, the symmetry group is pruned down to merely [SU(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Symmetry_group_of_the_3D_oscillator_Hamiltonian_operator).

The coincidence of the state degeneracy (n+1)(n+2)/2 with the irreducible representations of SU(3) is to be found in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/317363/66086); hint: take zero antiquarks!

*Note added on comment 2)*: I suspect you really are having me do your homework for you. In the "nice" variables above, your perturbation is but 
$$
2\lambda (Q_1^2 P_2^2 + Q_2^2P_1^2 - Q_1P_2Q_2P_1- Q_2P_1Q_1P_2).
$$
Proceed to collect to a square!

Comment: Ok, now my Hamiltonian is: $H_\lambda = H_{SHO} + 2 \lambda (Q_1 P_2 - Q_2P_1)^2$. Now the variables $Q_1$, $Q_2$, $P_1$, $P_2$, are mixed together with a term in $\lambda$. I suspect that the SU(3) invariance is broken. I am sure that there is a U(1) residual symmetry because the perturbation term does not include $(Q_3,P_3)$. Now I have to figure out if there is a subgroup of SU(3) that acts on $(Q_1,Q_2,P_1,P_2)$ which leaves the Hamiltonian invariant. I do not want the answer immediately, tell me if I am on the right way.

Comment: Yes, you are. . .

Comment: I don’t figure out, it seems that the only symmetry that remains is a U(1) symmetry...Is that correct? I need a hint...

Comment: Of the 8 Gell-Mann matrices, $\lambda_2$ commutes with itself and $\lambda_8$.

Comment: I have no idea how to continue. Please can you explain?

Comment: Sorry, but this is as far as the train goes. You note the commutator action of the square root of the perturbation on the Qs and Ps, and appreciate its correspondence to $\lambda_2$. You have a straightforward group theory problem with an explicit SU(3) breaking by $\lambda_2^2$.

Comment: If which sense the perturbed part corresponds to $\lambda_2^2$? I immagine the SU(3) generator as matrices and the Qs and Ps as the vector space.

Comment: Absolutely not. The *Q*s and *P*s are operators interconverting to each other by commutation with the bilinear of such comprising the 8 Gell-Mann matrices in the [Jordan map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map) realization. Once you master that, the rest should be easy.

Comment: Ok, maybe I have understood...if I express H in term of creation annihilation operators, the form of Hamiltonian is something like: $H = \omega (a^\dagger a) + \lambda a^\dagger \lambda_2^2 a$, where $a = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$. So the residual symmetries of the Hamiltonian are $a_i -> \lambda_{1,2,3} a_i$ and similar for $a^\dagger$, because $\lambda_{1,2,3}$ commute with $\lambda_2^2$. Is it correct? What algebra span $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\lambda_3$? Is it SU(2)?

Comment: Yes, it is the isospin subgroup. Times the U(1) generated by $\lambda_8$. They are described in the SU(3) article linked.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Since now the symmetry group is $SU(2)\times U(1)$ and the maximal commuting subset of the symmetry group seems to be $\{(\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_3^2),\lambda_3,\lambda_8\}$, in which way do the reps. depend on the eigenvalues of $\lambda_8$?

Comment: $\lambda_8$ does not connect $a_3$ with the other two oscillators: its action on them is basically the identity.

Comment: @CosmasZachos so I'm expecting that the eigenvalues will depend just on $l$ and $m$. Any hint about deriving their expressions?

Comment: No, but I'm interested in this problem. If I'm violating any rule, I will delete my last comment.

Comment: It's just that it might as well be a separate question. You are  right:  The perturbation is $(\vec a^\dagger \lambda_2 \vec a )^2$, which you may basis-rotate to $(\vec a^\dagger \lambda_3 \vec a )^2$, so then basically $J_3^2$ on the upper -2 oscillator space , and no action on the 3rd oscillator. All 3-oscillators are counted by the "kinetic" part of the question, while the relevant part of the perturbation are the states $|j,m\rangle= a_1^{\dagger ~j+m}  a_2^{\dagger ~j-m} |0\rangle /\sqrt{(j+m)!(j-m)!}$, where I have skipped a disconnected arbitrary number of 3rd-flavor oscillators....